# Can a discontinuous function have a continuous derivative?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Main Question: Is it possible for a function f to have a derivative at a point x but be discontinuous at that point?

Consider a function that is defined as follows:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2 & x \leq c \\ax+b & x > c \end{cases}$$
We are asked to find constants a,b,c such that the derivative of f at c exists.  Consider the situation where $a=2c$.  Following the limit definition of the derivative, we have that $f'(c)$ is equals to:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$$ provided that the limit is defined.
To see that, we may examine the limit as $x\to0-$ and as $x\to0+$.
$$\begin{equation}\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h} \\ =\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{a(c+h)+b-(ac+b)}{h}\end{equation}\\=\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{ah}{h}\\=a=2c$$
For when $x\to0-$:
$$\begin{equation}\lim_{h\to0-}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h} \\ =\lim_{h\to0-}\frac{(c+h)^2-c^2}{h}\end{equation}\\=\lim_{h\to0-}\frac{2ch+h^2}{h}\\=2c$$  Thus, by definition if $a=2c$ then for all values b $f'(c)$ exists and is equal to 2c.  Here is the issue, if $f'(c)$ exists for all values of b with the aforementioned condition then **it could certainly be possible that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at c** which contradicts an earlier theorem which states that if a function f has a derivative at a point x, then it is also continuous at x.
This is an example graph in desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/acym19fdm2.
This creates a situation where the function f has a derivative at the point x but it is not continuous at that point.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: As X-Rui and many others in the comments and answers pointed out, my error was in computing the right-hand limit.  f(c) should always be equal to $c^2$ regardless of the limit since c is constant and f(c) was so defined.  Hence the right-hand side limit computation should be as follows:

$$\begin{equation}\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h} \\ = \lim_{h\to0+}\frac{a(c+h)+b-c^2}{h}\end{equation}$$

From here we intend to find an values of a,b,c such that this limit will agree with the value of the left limit of 2c.  Assume that there exists such a value c, then since f is differentiable at c f is continuous at c.  Hence $ac+b=c^2$ by continuity (as pointed out by stoic-santiago).  Then the limit above simplifies to $$\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{a(c+h)+b-(ac+b)}{h}=a$$  Hence our requirement of differentiability simplifies to the requirement that $a=2c$ (along with the above requirement for continuity).

Therefore, any a,b,c satisfying the two conditions $ac+b=c^2$ and $a=2c$ will suffice.

Comment: Easy consequence of definition of derivative: If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ then it is continuous at $c$.

Comment: My question is that this example contradicts that.  For a certain choice of b f is not continuous.  See the graph in desmos.

Comment: @procommania There is no contradiction. If the limit $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists and is finite, then $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h) = f(x)$. This is inevitable. Just use the definitions to see it.

Comment: Your example does not contradicts the theorem, the function is not differentiable.

Comment: Differentiability is established by the limit.  I believe I have shown that the limit exists.

Comment: I won’t give the answer here in the comments, but I’ll indeed point out some errors. 1, you take the wrong sides when calculating the one-sided derivatives. Also, $f(c)$ should be $c^2$ no matter which side you are taking the limit from; this would show you the function has to be continuous at $c$.

Comment: @procommania Suppose the limit exists. Consider
$$f(x+h) - f(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \cdot h.$$ As $h\to 0$, $ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \to f'(x)$, and $h\to 0$, so the product vanishes. We have continuity.

Comment: There might be something very obvious that I am not seeing here.  I have read through the proof for the theorem and I am very much inclined to think that I have done something wrong, but I don't quite get it.

Comment: As @X-Rui points out, the mistake is in your left-side limit, procommania. Look at the function: $f(c)=c^2,$ but you used wrongly $ac+b.$

Comment: My bad.  I will edit that.  But the point should still stand.

Comment: In response to stoic-santiago, I am familiar with that specific proof of the theorem.  If you will open the graph in desmos, it shows that this function is discontinuous but the derivative is continuous.

Comment: @procommania If you choose $b$ such that this function is discontinuous, then the derivative will not be defined at $x = c$. I would trust the mathematicians on this site over Desmos about this. This should be apparent once you correct the error in the evaluation of the first limit as pointed out by X-Rui. If the graph is discontinuous at $c$, how is the right limit finite? Even geometrically; think about what is happening to the secant line interpolating $(c,f(c))$ and $(c+h, f(c+h))$ as $h \to 0^+$.

Comment: You have not edited the question to reflect the comment by @X-Rui. So your computation of the right hand limit for the derivative is incorrect. Until you fix that most of your argument is meaningless.

Comment: The main thing you are doing wrong here is assuming Desmos will notice and correctly handle the situation that happens at at just one point, i.e. $c$. It does not, and a proper graph of the derivative would have an open circle there, indicating that it is not defined there.

Comment: I sort of see your point.  But we choose b such that the function is discontinuous at c, not the derivative.  Since in the difference quotient the constant b disappears , the limit as h goes to zero of that quotient is defined and hence the derivative is defined (if we use the limit definition of the derivative).  I have corrected the first error pointed out by X-Rui.  The second point is addressed above.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I see the issue.

Comment: Excellent. You might want to add an answer, or add on to your question, explaining what the issue was. That way future readers can benefit, and the people who have replied can see that their comments had a benefit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your main mistake is you used the wrong definition of $f$ at $c$ when calculating the right-sided limit. You wrote
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(c+h) - \color{red}{f(c)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{a(c+h)+b - \color{red}{(ac+b)}}{h},$$
where you used $f(c) = ac + b$. This is wrong. By definition, $f(c) = c^2$, no matter which side you are taking the limit from. The correct calculation should be
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(c+h) - \color{red}{f(c)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{a(c+h)+b - \color{red}{c^2}}{h}.$$
From here, you can follow the classic proof to show $f$ must be continuous at $c$.

What you calculated was (virtually) the left-sided and the right-sided limits of the derivative of $f$ at $c$. Them being equal does not mean $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Likely not. If *f* is differentiable at a point *x*, then *f* must also be continuous at *x*, locally linear (the reverse does not hold). If *f* is even not differentiable at a point *x*, how it could be as much as continuous derivative there.